# Java 1.7.21 install via GPO fails on Win 8

Tags: group-policy, java

Attempting to distribute Java runtime 7 update 21 via GPO to Windows 8.

Problem is the GPO fails with:

> The install of application Java 7 Update 21 (64-bit) from policy
>   Workstation 64-bit failed. The error was: %%1612

Then try running it manually but that fails with:

> There was a problem starting C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\installer.dll
>   The specified module could not be found.

Is anyone else having difficulties with this version of Java?

Comment: I don't have any input to you, but I just double-checked and I am successfully deploying the 32-bit MSI for Java 7 Update 21 to Windows 8 Pro computers via Group Policy. There are only 2 machines running Windows 8 that it applies to (a Surface Pro and a Dell OptiPlex 9010 pre-loaded from Dell) but it is applying successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the info Evan.  Sounds like it might be a 64-bit only problem then.